# 4790k Haswell CPU temps 99C ? is it ok?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

Hi all I am using a stock cooler and have the above CPU. My specs are:

```
z97-P
4790k @ 4GHz (stock cooler, not overclocked)
1060GTX 6GB
32GB Ram 800Mhz
405w PSU
```

I am now using Unreal Engine, alongside 3d dev apps such as Maya and also streaming Youtube at same time.  The PC seems very loud a lot of the time now but the CPU usage doesnt go over around 50% ever.

But I decided to get HWinfo64. And it tells me the CPU cores are at 99C.

All the websites I checked said 79C max. http://www.buildcomputers.net/cpu-temperature.html  //  I could not find exact max temps on offical Intel websites.

I really don't want to buy/fit new coolers. But this is winter, and summer will come soon. Do I need to upgrade the cooler or is 99C ok. I sometimes use PC for over 20 hours non-stop.

Sensors readings:

[image]

Comment: Based on the usage you describe those temperatures are not normal.  They are within the operating temperatures of the CPU, but they are not normal, those temperatures indicate you don't have adequate cooling.  I have a 4700K (which is basically a 4790k), run it at 24/7 at 100% most of the time, and my temperatures don't even get near 99C

Comment: Oh that's bad news. I have added the screenshot of Sensors panel from HWINFO to the question. If this sheds any further light on the temps reading. Appreciate your help

Comment: You have not actually added any screenshots.  Your question has received no edits.

Comment: Are you sure its not a cache issue or something. It says it is there on mine, however it is a link rather than directly showing the image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw3nW.png

Comment: One last question @Ramhound . Would 'underclocking' my CPU ever be advisable here (even as temporary fix before I get cooler)?

Comment: According to Intel it is 74 degrees centigrade, see Tcase spec>>>>>https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80807/intel-core-i7-4790k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html

Comment: damn i see. So am i causing lasting damage here? Been using it like this potentially for years?

Comment: @Krangogram - No;  Your CPU is overheating, more then likely, it's actually just thermal.  You need to resolve that problem.  **Your current cooling is inadequate.**  99C isn't going to do any damage to the silicon, but you are likely, not seeing the type of performance you would if your cooling was adequate.

Comment: ok. well hopefully I dont break anything when i delve in to fit a cooler lol

Comment: Did you  use top quality thermal paste and apply it properly? Is the heatsink attached  properly?

Comment: Well I bought it as a bundle . Mobo with prefitted CPU and cooler. The seller had over 500,000 positive 99.9% feedback

Comment: I might try then , to clean inside computer and to re-apply best quality thermal paste

Comment: If you've always felt your PC was slow under load...you've got your culprit. xD Have you tried another temperature program?

Comment: Honestly the PC does feel quick and seems to perform well. It doesnt crash or anything. I havent tried any other programs since reading around it seems hwinfo was best for Intel due it giving each cores temperature

Comment: Well, hwinfo does tell you you're thermal throttling (core #2) so it cant be all that good. Do post pictures of the inside of the PC when possible. The cooler might be too small for this 88W cpu.

Comment: ok i will post pictures. Although it is embarassingly dirty in there lol

Comment: @Krangogram - Please don't submit a screenshot of a PC that is fully of dirt, we are just going to tell you to clean the PC, and submit new screenshots.  Anyways, my previous comment was incomplete, your CPU is being thermally throttled.  Instead of screenshots of a cooler we won't be able to identify, provide the model, of the cooler itself (although again your cooling inadequate so you really should address that issue).

Comment: It is Intel E97378-001 . CNDP519K40 - DTC-DAA16 12VDC 0.60A. I took a photo and it is very dirty below the fan (which i couldnt see without flash). I actually think a good clean might fix it :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend always using intel's spec sheets for information about their products.

For your CPU: [i7-4790K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80807/intel-core-i7-4790k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html)

If you scroll down, you can see it's T^Case is 74.04C and it's TDP is 88w. To answer your question:  No 99*C is not good for this CPU for an extended period of time. Yes you will need to upgrade your cooling to handle the current workload.

When selecting a Fan, you need to find one with a TDP dissipation set to higher than the CPU's TDP of 88. Ambient temperatures matter when cooling, especially air cooling.  So throwing a 90 TDP rated CPU cooler while the ambient air/case air is relatively hot, may not suffice.

There are tons of fan with prime 150+ TDPs for less than $30 to be found. According to the Spec sheet you will see your socketed as an LGA 1150. Just make sure you search for fans of this supported socket.  IE Newegg filtered results:  [Here](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100008000%20601312594)